# Outer apply takes a long time when it contains string compare in it

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, outer-apply

I have a query:

```
with cte as
(   
//some select statement
)
    select -
    // also some code here
     from cte a 
     outer apply
(select top 1 position,traffic,tags,url,Domain,Load_Date,trend_date
    from cte b 
    where b.Date_ID<=a.Date_ID and 
        b.Load_Date is not null and 
        a.Domain is null and 
        a.Project_Id=b.Project_Id and
        a.SE_Id=b.SE_Id  and
        a.Keyword=b.keyword 
        order by a.Date_ID desc
        )x
```

My `cte` returns almost 3 million rows. This query takes a very long time to finish (every 4 minutes it returns only 500 rows)

But the following query without `Keyword` compare in outer apply, is very fast:

```
with cte as
(   
//some select statement
)
    select 
    // also some code here
     from cte a 
     outer apply
(select top 1 position,traffic,tags,url,Domain,Load_Date,trend_date
    from cte b 
    where b.Date_ID<=a.Date_ID and 
        b.Load_Date is not null and 
        a.Domain is null and 
        a.Project_Id=b.Project_Id and
        a.SE_Id=b.SE_Id  and
        order by a.Date_ID desc
        )x
```

The Problem is, that I need this Keyword comparison in my query. My question is now, How should I change my original query to have a better performance?
good to know:

- Project_Id is `int`
- SE_Id is `int`
- Keyword is `nvarchar(2000)`

Comment: You would have to examine the execution plans.  In all likelihood. the first allows the use of an index.

Comment: What is a "Mio"?

Comment: @Larnu `Milion`

Comment: I would suggest you try to load your data into a temporary table instead of using cte in this case.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin I have test it, but not a big change in performance

Comment: @DenisRubashkinMy temporary table had also no index

Answer (score 0):

Include `Keyword` in the index(es) being used by the second query.